# What are the steps for configuring schemacrawler in Eclipse IDE and how do I use this API?

Tags: schemacrawler

Good evening

I am a student in the engineering of distributed systems Master 2.

I wanted to know how to use the SchemaCrawler API to implement an application that generates metadata from a database (Mysql) and use the metadata to create an entity association diagram (reverse engineering).

If you want to help me in my work.

Thank you .

Comment: Where I have to put the schemacrawler.config.properties file ??

Answer (score 1):

> Where I have to put the schemacrawler.config.properties file ??

If you are using the SchemaCrawler API, you do not need a `schemacrawler.config.properties` file. The configuration file is used to build the `SchemaCrawlerOptions`, which you can build programmatically. Please see this [code example](https://gist.github.com/sualeh/63e4b8cb0515c6e928e7a9a419f46411#file-schemacrawler_gist-java) to get started.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com)

Comment: Thank you, I will see

Comment: the method getConnection () is undefined for the type schemacrawler_gist . Eclipde IDE  asks me to create method getConnection () ;

Comment: Please take a look at [ApiExample.java](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sualeh/SchemaCrawler/2df132933c19f473f23f30fad82c0faef082a603/schemacrawler-examplecode/src/main/java/ApiExample.java)

Comment: I already have a look and full of instructions that is not right

Comment: In this instruction I put the driver and url of database .

Comment: final DataSource dataSource =
      new DatabaseConnectionOptions("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projet");       In this instruction I put the driver and url of database .

Comment: He asks me to exchange these two methods options.setRoutineInclusionRule(new ExcludeAll()); 
    options 
      .setSchemaInclusionRule(new RegularExpressionInclusionRule("PUBLIC.BOOKS"));   and wath That I have to put in place of "PUBLIC.BOOKS"

Comment: I have not found any tutorial or courses that explains or facilitates the use of this API

Comment: Please refer to the javadocs - http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/apidocs/index.html

Comment: please ; I have not found a solution for the method getConnection ();Catalog catalog = SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog(connection, options); the method getConnection () is it Predefined in SchemaCrawler API
Or customize ?? I have an error in this method. i have to  create it bye  myself ??

Comment: please ; I have not found a solution for the method getCatalog ();Catalog catalog = SchemaCrawlerUtility.getCatalog(connection, options); the method getCatalog () is it Predefined in SchemaCrawler API
Or customize ?? I have an error in this method. i have to  create it bye  myself ??